# debugging ignored files and folder

Tags: git

I have a problem with my git repo. I could be caused by PyCharm plugin for git. The problem is that some files are not being tracked.

```
$ touch src/.../icon/x.txt
$ git status
# On branch xxx
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

it is tracked in different location. `src/icon/x.txt` is also ignored so I tried to look for a pattern that could match that. But it looks ok. I deleted the repo and cloned it again. I looked for global config and global ignore but there is nothing.

Is there a way to tell which rule is matching that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `git check-ignore src/icon/x.txt -v`

in /Users/me/.config/git/ignore

```
# Automatically created by GitHub for Mac

.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
Icon  <- match my icon folder
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are looking for [git check-ignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html). It's basic usage should be exactly what you are looking for:

```
git check-ignore src/abc/x.txt
```

Comment: git: 'check-ignore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. I updated it to 1.8.3.4 and still no cmd

Comment: Strange because the `git check-ignore` command has been introduced in 1.8.2

Comment: same here.   no idea.